# How to write update trigger based on a requirement

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

Apologies for the alignment im new so having some trouble.
Hi guys I'm learning SQL server for the first time and the concept of the trigger is a little tricky. I missed my update trigger and now having trouble implementing them practically. coming to the question we have two tables one is

```
    UserMaster
    
    Column Name     Data Type      Remarks
    USERID          INTEGER        Primary Key
    USER NAME       VARCHAR(30)    NOT NULL
    DESIGNATION     CHAR(1)        ‘M’ for ‘MANAGER’, ‘T’ for ‘TELLER’, ‘C’ for ‘CLERK’, ‘O’ for ‘OFFICER’; NOT NULL.

TransactioMaster

Column Name         Data Type      Remarks
TRANSACTION NUMBER  INTEGER        Primary Key; Identity, seed=1, Increment=1; 
DATE OF TRANSACTION DATETIME       NOT NULL
ACID                INTEGER        Foreign Key; NOT NULL
BRID                CHAR(3)        Foreign Key; NOT NULL
TXN_TYPE            CHAR(3)        ‘CW’ for ‘CASH WITHDRAWAL’, ‘CD’ for ‘CASH 
                                   DEPOSIT’, ‘CQD’ for ‘CHEQUE DEPOSIT’; NOT NULL 
CHQ_NO              INTEGER        NULL ALLOWED
CHQ_DATE            SMALLDATETIME  NULL ALLOWED
TXN_AMOUNT          MONEY          NOT NULL
USERID              INTEGER        Foreign Key; NOT NULL
```

Question 1
When a Transaction is altered, the difference between the old amount and the new amount cannot be more than 10%, if the transaction has been affected by the teller

Question 2
More than three Cash Withdrawal transactions in a single account on the same day should not be allowed

My code which i tried

I tried some logic but it seems not working. Can some one help me with the logic.

```
    USE [casestudy]
```

GO

```
ALTER trigger [dbo].[UDT_transaction_altered]
on [dbo].[TransactionMaster]
after update
as 
begin
declare @old_userid int
declare @new_userid int
declare @acid int
declare @newamt money
declare @oldamt money
declare @diffamt money
declare @10perct money
declare @designation char(1)

--Get teller info and txn_amount Info
select @old_userid = userid, @oldamt = TXN_AMOUNT from deleted --contains old data
select @acid = acid, @new_userid = userid, @newamt = TXN_AMOUNT from inserted --contains new data


set @diffamt = @newamt - @oldamt
set @10perct = (0.1 * @oldamt) + @oldamt

if update(TXN_AMOUNT)
    begin
        if (@diffamt < 0)
            begin 
                print ' TXN_AMOUNT canot be negative' 
                print ' Transaction declined'
                rollback
            end
            if(@newamt > @10perct)
            begin
                print ' New TXN_AMOUNT canot be more than 10% of old amount' 
                print ' Transaction declined'
                rollback
            end
            else
            begin
                update TransactionMaster set TXN_AMOUNT = @newamt where acid = @acid
            end
    end
end

    

/* select TransactionNumber, acid , tm.USERID,designation ,count(*) as nooftrans from TransactionMaster tm join usermaster um
on tm.userid = um.USERID
where datediff(dd,dot,getdate()) = 0 and um.designation = 'T'
group by TransactionNumber, ACID,tm.USERID ,Designation
order by ACID
```

Is this query correct to get whether the transaction was done by the teller or not?*/
end
can someone help me with these two triggers' logic? I'm trying but I'm not able to get the logic.

Comment: I guess it is better for you to know that inserted/deleted-tables in the MS SQL Server-trigger can contain more than one record. So this assignment select old_userid = userid, oldamt = TXN_AMOUNT from deleted --contains old data  is incorrect. And I guess sample data and desired output will help us to help you

Comment: Strongly recommended reading: [Bad Habits to Kick : Abusing triggers](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-abusing-triggers)

Comment: Also, why are you `PRINT`ing **informational** messages that look to be more like they need to be errors and then instead cause a generic `The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.` error? Why not `THROW` an informative error, and have the outer transaction rollback the transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of serious bugs in your trigger

- `inserted` and `deleted` can contain multiple rows. You need to join them based on the primary key
- Instead of `PRINT` and `ROLLBACK` use `THROW`
- You also need to add the trigger for `INSERT`
- `money` is a bad data type for most purposes, due to rounding. Use `decimal` instead.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER trigger dbo.UDT_transaction_altered
ON dbo.TransactionMaster
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;  -- prevent spurious resultsets
    
IF UPDATE(TXN_AMOUNT)  -- only checks for presence in statement, still need to check values
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
        FROM deleted d
        JOIN inserted i ON i.[TRANSACTION NUMBER] = d.[TRANSACTION NUMBER] -- join on PK
        WHERE i.TXN_AMOUNT NOT BETWEEN d.TXN_AMOUNT AND d.TXN_AMOUNT * 1.1)
BEGIN    
    THROW 50001, 'TXN_AMOUNT canot be negative or more than 10% of old amount', 1;
END;

IF (UPDATE(ACID)  -- only checks for presence in statement, still need to check values
    OR UPDATE([DATE OF TRANSACTION]))
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM inserted i
    JOIN TransactionMaster tm
        ON tm.ACID = i.ACID
       AND tm.[DATE OF TRANSACTION] >= CAST(CAST(i.[DATE OF TRANSACTION] AS date) AS datetime)
       AND tm.[DATE OF TRANSACTION] < CAST(DATEADD(day, 1, CAST(i.[DATE OF TRANSACTION] AS date)) AS datetime)
    GROUP BY
      tm.ACID
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CAST(tm.[DATE OF TRANSACTION] AS date)) > 3)
BEGIN
    THROW 50001, 'More than three transactions not allowed', 1;
END;
go
```

For this trigger to work efficiently you are going to want an index on

```sql
TransactionMaster (ACID, [DATE OF TRANSACTION])
```

I recommend you don't use column names that need quoting with `[]`, it's really annoying.